# Google Maps from Razor

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-modal

**How can I get Google Maps from another Razor ?**

Hello everyone,
I'm trying to solve the problem ...
Google Maps Javascript in Create.cshtml, the problem is in Index.cshtml.

Index button calls Create.cshtml a Modal Boostrap.

How do Index.cshtml getting from a Create.cshtml.

Modal works correct, but Google Maps does not work.

*Create.cshtml*

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <!-- 'has-error' class has been added on parent form-group div -->
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Create</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">


                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.GoogleMaps, new { @class = "col-xs-3 control-label" })
                        <div class="col-xs-5">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GoogleMaps, new { @id = "pac-input", @class = "controls", placeholder = "Search" })
                            <div id="map" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                  


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

*Javascript*

```
function initAutocomplete() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195 },
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function () {
        searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });

    var markers = [];
    // [START region_getplaces]
    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
    // more details for that place.
    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function () {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

        if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        // Clear out the old markers.
        markers.forEach(function (marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
        });
        markers = [];

        // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        places.forEach(function (place) {
            var icon = {
                url: place.icon,
                size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };

            // Create a marker for each place.
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                icon: icon,
                title: place.name,
                position: place.geometry.location
            }));

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                // Only geocodes have viewport.
                bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
                bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
    // [END region_getplaces]
}

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
    async defer></script>
```

*Index.cshtml*

```
        <div class="pull-right col-lg-1">
            <a class="btn btn-success" onclick="OpenCreatePopup()">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            </a>
        </div>

<div id="DivToAppendPartialView"></div>


<script>
    function OpenCreatePopup() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $('#DivToAppendPartialView').load("/Account/Create", function () {
            $('#myModal').modal({
                keyboard: true
            }, 'show');
        });
        return false;
};

</script>
```

Problem is not showing Google Maps in modal Bootstrap.

Help me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution !

```
 .pac-container {
  z-index: 100000;
}
```

Google Maps in modal boostrap work !