# Ionic 2 - Modal: Google Map not assigned to div

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an implementation using google maps js api. It works perfectly when I run it in a component. However, I want it to display in a modal. When I run it in a modal, it gets no errors reported and the map object seems to be created, the div can be found, but it just does not render the map. The modal is displayed, all the html renders, but the map is just not displayed.

For details please see:  https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/modal-map-not-assigned-to-div/58867

Comment: Can it be similar to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624650/google-maps-from-razor/38627093#38627093)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried adding the css, but it didn't make a difference.